# Exluding elements in an array

Tags: php

I have a two dimentional array called $companies:

```
           $companies[] = array(
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'contactid' => $row['contactid'],
                    'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
                    'email' => $row['email']        
            );
```

And I want to assign it to a new array but only include firstname, lastname and email and leave out the others.

How would I do this?

Comment: use a for loop and transfer the values you want into the new array

Comment: Is there not a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know about elegant, but you could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: not to my knowledge, but there might be as I dont know everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple create a new array based on your actual array:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    $newArray[] = array(
        'firstname' => $company['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $company['lastname'],
        'email' => $company['email'],
    );
}
```

You can do this also, when you build your original array.

Answer (score 2):

Using `array_map()` (not exactly elegant):

```
$array = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        return [
            'firstname' => $item['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $item['lastname'],
            'email' => $email
        ];
    },
    $companies
);
```